# Having problems with Code::Blocks while setting up SFML static library

Tags: build, codeblocks, sfml

First of all, I have to say that I'm only a beginner with c++ programming so it's the first time ever I try to set up sfml 2.4.0. I'm running Code::Blocks on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The script with the error is the same as the tutorial on SFML's official site:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow finestra (sf::VideoMode(100,100), "Ciao!");
    sf::CircleShape cerchio (100.f);
    cerchio.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    while (finestra.isOpen())
    {
    sf::Event evento;
    while (finestra.pollEvent(evento))
    {
    if (evento.type == sf::Event::Closed)
    finestra.close();
    }
    finestra.clear();
    finestra.draw(cerchio);
    finestra.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Don't mind for strange names to variables and strings, I just wanted to get more familiar with the script using terms of my language.
The error appearing after I tried to build and run the script is this ("riferimento non definito a" means "undefined reference to"):

```
||=== Build: Debug in primo_game_magari_serio (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|106|riferimento non definito a "glClearColor"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|107|riferimento non definito a "glClear"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|276|riferimento non definito a "glVertexPointer"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|277|riferimento non definito a "glColorPointer"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|278|riferimento non definito a "glTexCoordPointer"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|287|riferimento non definito a "glDrawArrays"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|311|riferimento non definito a "glGetError"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|321|riferimento non definito a "glPushClientAttrib"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|322|riferimento non definito a "glPushAttrib"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|324|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|325|riferimento non definito a "glPushMatrix"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|326|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|327|riferimento non definito a "glPushMatrix"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|328|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|329|riferimento non definito a "glPushMatrix"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|341|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|342|riferimento non definito a "glPopMatrix"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|343|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|344|riferimento non definito a "glPopMatrix"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|345|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|346|riferimento non definito a "glPopMatrix"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|348|riferimento non definito a "glPopClientAttrib"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|349|riferimento non definito a "glPopAttrib"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|374|riferimento non definito a "glDisable"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|375|riferimento non definito a "glDisable"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|376|riferimento non definito a "glDisable"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|377|riferimento non definito a "glDisable"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|378|riferimento non definito a "glEnable"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|379|riferimento non definito a "glEnable"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|380|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|381|riferimento non definito a "glEnableClientState"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|382|riferimento non definito a "glEnableClientState"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|383|riferimento non definito a "glEnableClientState"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|419|riferimento non definito a "glViewport"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|422|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|423|riferimento non definito a "glLoadMatrixf"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|426|riferimento non definito a "glMatrixMode"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|444|riferimento non definito a "glBlendFunc"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.cpp|485|riferimento non definito a "glLoadMatrixf"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Shader.cpp|64|riferimento non definito a "glGetIntegerv"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Shader.cpp|984|riferimento non definito a "glFlush"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|66|riferimento non definito a "glGetIntegerv"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|72|riferimento non definito a "glGetIntegerv"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|124|riferimento non definito a "glDeleteTextures"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|166|riferimento non definito a "glGenTextures"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|214|riferimento non definito a "glBindTexture"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|215|riferimento non definito a "glTexImage2D"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|216|riferimento non definito a "glTexParameteri"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|217|riferimento non definito a "glTexParameteri"|
/usr/local/share/buildslave/tmp/build/src/SFML/Graphics/Texture.cpp|218|riferimento non definito a "glTexParameteri"|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Here there are the project's build option (the ones I don't mention are set to default):

Search Directories/Compiler: /home/user/Downloads/SFML-2.4.0/include

Search Directories/Linker: /home/user/Downloads/SFML-2.4.0/lib (I also tried to add another "/include" but it didn't work too)

Linker Settings/Debug/sfml-graphics-s-d
sfml-window-s-d
sfml-system-s-d

Linker Settings/Release/sfml-graphics-s
sfml-window-s
sfml-system-s

Compiler Settings/#defines/SFML_STATIC

I searched for over a week in very single thread like these on the forum, but I never found the same problem as mine. If you need other information just ask, thank you in advance.

Comment: The undefined references are to opengl.  You will need to add the opengl library ( in windows it is opengl32, do not know about linux )

Comment: Than You very much, I'll look for it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

The undefined references are to opengl. You will need to add the opengl library.

In windows that would be `opengl32`, added after all the sfml libraries

In linux, I am not so certain, but it looks like `GL`

( It is strange that the SFML docs do not mention this.  The windows version at https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-cb.php does mention the dependency, but the screenshot does not show the library reference.  The linux build instructions do not mention it at all!  When you get this working, you should ask them to updated the docs. )

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll certainly ask to the team after I have fixed this.

Comment: Ok, after having updated the opengl packages I managed to compile the file on the terminal adding "-lglut" between "g++" and the sfml installation path, everything went well while recompiling the main.o with the libraries too. It finally worked, but do you know where to put the - lglut command on project's build settings?

Comment: Add glut to the list of libraries in linker settings, and the library folder to the list of linker search directories.

Comment: I can't find glut's libray path because I installed it with the terminal, "whereis" doesn't work too. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, some time passed. At the end I tried as you Said, and that worked! Ty very much